# Longtable - set table text and NOT caption to tiny

Tags: longtable

EDIT: I cannot use usepackage{caption} for this, it ruins my captions.

I need to make a longtable such that the table text, but not the caption, is tiny.

This example is obviously too short to merit a longtable but it does show my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\tiny
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\caption{{\normalsize A nice caption}}
\label{1}\\
 \hline 1 & 2 \\
 \hline 1 & 2 \\
 \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

And the picture of the output (See how "table 1" is not normalsize?):

[image: NA]

I've looked at the manual for longtable and a few longtable questions on here, but none that cover exactly this situation.

Comment: use `\usepackage{caption}`.

Comment: A general remark: *Never* encase a `longtable` environment on a `center` environment. Never, ever.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I have to change my outcome. Using the caption package ruins the formatting on my captions.

Comment: the caption package is quite powerful, read the docu.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: **(i)** tables with `\tiny` font size are hard to read, see if you can use larger font size (for example `\footnotesize`, **(ii)** you should show us, how you define your captions style; so far is not clear, why you not allowed to use `caption` package.

Comment: Newer version of longtable are compatible with the caption package.  Try updating your packages.  Also, you can use `\begingroup\tiny ... \endgroup` or `{\tiny ... }`.

Comment: Do you supply each reader with a magnifying glass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to define a column type that is tiny and centered (using `\newcolumntype` from the `array` package) and use that for all columns.

However, as mentioned in the comments, tiny table contents is not very readable, maybe you can consider presenting the information differently.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\tiny}c}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|T|T|}
\caption{A nice caption}
\label{1}\\
 \hline 1 & 2 \\
 \hline 1 & 2 \\
 \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant idea. Thank you.